# Create/Modify Excel spreadsheet without using a Com Object in PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell, report, powershell-2.0, spreadsheet

Is there a way to generate an excel spreadsheet using PowerShell without using a Com Object? I have a few really ugly scripts that open an Excel Com Object, add data, run some macros, and save the file to create reports I need. If I could define spreadsheet formatting, then convert a csv to that format using PowerShell, I assume it would be faster, and an overall better script. How could I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: Without any COM object or just without the Excel object?  Here is a way with OleDb: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/15/how-can-i-write-to-excel-without-using-excel.aspx

Comment: @RichardMorgan I don't want to have Excel installed on the system the script is running on. Is there a format that can be written/defined in plain text (similar to XML) to create custom reports?

Comment: @RichardMorgan I also would want to add color/formatting to cells where necessary.

Comment: If you want to apply formatting and execute VBA inside the workbook, I think your only option is to invoke Excel via COM. A plain dump of the data to CSV can be done via OleDb or ODBC, but beyond that you're into Excel territory.

Comment: @alroc I actually would prefer not to keep the VBA, and instead define the formatting elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the workbooks `.xls` or `.xlsx` files? The latter are basically a bunch of XML files in a Zip archive, so you could extract the XML files from the archive and proceed from there. If you need to hand-craft a `.xlsx` file [this posting](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/fb.ashx?m=71130) on visualbasicscript.com may help.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I want. I'll look into developing reports using the Office XML format.

Comment: For very simple spreadsheets, it could be an idea to take a look at the "Excel xml spreadsheet 2003" file format, which is plain xml, no need for un/zipping. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats

Answer (score 0):

If you are satisfied with accessing the raw data in the spreadsheet/workbook, dumping it to CSV, and/or doing some additional processing outside Excel, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15537692/1324345) for getting started with accessing the data via ODBC & `System.Data`.