# Why is it so slow to read an Excel file with Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a small Excel file with 28 KB in XLSX format and I would like to modify it with Powershell. The file contains 59 rows and 366 columns.

My code walks through the first column and searches for a specific entry and after that it walks through the column found and outputs the content of the found row and the fist row. This is the code:

```
# Define some parameters.
$year = "2015"
$filename = "C:\...\file.xlsx"
$person = "Lastname, Firstname"

# Open Excel file and select worksheet.
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filename)
$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item($year)
$cells = $worksheet.cells

# Search person name in first column.
$rows = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
"Rows: $rows"
$row = 1

while ($row -le $rows)
{
  $cell = $cells.item($row,1).value2
  if ($person -eq $cell) {
    break
  }
  $row++
}

# List row
$cols = $worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.count
"Cols: $cols"
foreach ($col in 2..$cols)
{
  $date = $cells.item(1,$col).value2
  $data = $cells.item($row,$col).value2
  $date = [DateTime]::FromOADate($date)
  $msg = $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + $data
  "$msg"
}

# Close workbook and Excel file and release COM object.
$workbook.close()
$excel.quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
```

My problem: The program is terrible slow. It takes more than 5 minutes to iterate the 366 columns!

```
PS C:\...> Measure-Command { .\program.ps1 }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 5
Seconds           : 33
Milliseconds      : 580
Ticks             : 3335806616
TotalDays         : 0,00386088728703704
TotalHours        : 0,0926612948888889
TotalMinutes      : 5,55967769333333
TotalSeconds      : 333,5806616
TotalMilliseconds : 333580,6616
```

I can hardly believe that this is normal. Instead I think that there is something really wrong with my program. But I have no idea what it is.

What do I have to change to make it faster?

Comment: Do you need to work with this in excel. We could programmically convert the data into csv in order to manipulate it. This is not meant to answer why it is slow.

Comment: @Matt The Excel file has much decoration and many functions and it seems to me that it would be much work to preserve this information. This is the reason why I have scrapped my Perl solution, which also would have to build the new Excel file from scratch, because it exists a Perl module to read Excel files and one to write Excel files but none to update Excel files.

Comment: I did not mean lose the excel file. Just work with it as a csv copy. We can do that programmically. No change to the excel. You do not appear to save changes just query data.

Comment: @Matt Yes the update is still missing, because I spend my day investigating, why the read is so slow. But in the end I have to update the Excel file.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [Is there a faster way to parse an xml document with powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15550576/115690). Even if not a precise duplicate, I suspect my answer there could assist you.

Comment: Going cell by cell in excel with powershell is very slow. You should use a range, put it in a variable then do stuff with that variable. I'm sorry I don't have excel on my computer right now to test by you could probably use something like:
`$range = $worksheet.UsedRange;` and `$array = $range.Value2;`

Answer (score 0):

Using loop and find to replace cell values in Excel will take you forever... I have 111 cells to replace and it takes about 40 secs to complete.
However, you may exploit the command Replace which is considerably faster. But to provide a value from a relative cell you have to change your Excel application Reference style to xlR1c1. 
Below is my take on how I can replace all cells with string "No registered hostname" with a value of the cell to the left which is IP address for my data.
I have commented out the while loop which I previously used
Since you intend to do an update you may consider this...

```
$Range=$WorkSheet.Range("B1").EntireColumn
# Replace Cells with No registered hostname
$SearchString="No registered hostname"
# Using Excel reference style xlR1C1 to set the formula for replace
$xls.Application.ReferenceStyle=2 
$Range.Replace($SearchString, "=RC[-1]")
# while ($NoDNS=$Range.find($SearchString))
#   {
#   $NoDNS.Activate()
#   $RefRow=$NoDNS.Row
#   $NoDNS.value()=$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($RefRow, 1).Text
#   }
$xls.Application.ReferenceStyle=1
```

Using replace only takes a split second to complete all the necessary changes compare to previous while loop.